# Zeitwerk vs list of classes in a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zeitwerk

I'm trying to cache a class list and I'm wondering how it is supposed to be done with zeitwerk.

I obtain the class list like:

```rb
    def models
      return @models if @models

      Zeitwerk::Loader.eager_load_all # this is to see all models in dev env, otherwise some may not be yet loaded, hence not present in the list
      @models = ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.select { |model| model.include?(SomeModule) }
    end
```

But then any moment zeitwerk may reload the classes and invalidate content of `@model`. This is my understanding.

So how am I supposed to have a cache of classes in a Rails dev environment?

Bonus question, how do I eager load a single directory programatically? That is to load only what is needed to be loaded instead of the whole app.

P.S. This class list will only be used in specific `rake` tasks and in tests, not in production runtime code. Just saying to avoid complaints that this should not be done.

Update (just illustration of how it's done):

```rb
class ModelFoo
  annotated
  ...
end
class ModelBar
  annotated
  ...
end
module Annotating
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module Model
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      has_many :annotations, as: :annotated, dependent: :destroy, autosave: true
    end

    ...
  end
  class_methods do
    def annotated
      class_eval do
        include Model
      end
    end
  end

  class << self
    def models
      <see above the body of this method>
    end
  end
end
ActiveRecord::Base.include(Annotating::Model)
```

Later use `Annotating.models` to generate a trigger for all annotated models and for testing all annotated models with some standard operations.

Comment: "this should not be done" - you nailed that one. cache - implies some performance improvement vs no cache, are you getting any significant improvement here? `bootsnap` and `spring` already do a pretty good job at "caching". "used in specific rake tasks" - that seems totally useless, when you run a rake task the whole environment is loaded there is no way to have a memoized @model at that point to get any benefit. "and in tests" - same thing. "zeitwerk may reload the classes" - yeah, during development, not during tests or when you run a rake task, reload happens on file change.

Comment: maybe if you can explain your usecase, there could be a better/different way of doing what you need to do here. but anyway, I have had the need to have a list of classes, i think I've solved by using `constantize` when needed without memoization.

Comment: @Alex, The use case that broke is automatically creating database triggers for all models that include the module. This is done as part of database migration. In dev mode at `db:migrate:up` only one of the models is found and triggers for the rest of them are not generated. It's somehow frustrating to implement workarounds just for dev mode...

Comment: And what happens when migration runs and after that you include the module in another model? Migration will not run again. New model will not have trigger. Trying to do magic in database migrations is usually bad practice. They should be a simple and dumb as possible because ideally they will continue to work even if the application code changes (is refactored).

Comment: Also what if 2 developers run the migration at different times. The model list might be different, now you have different databases. Annoying for development. But what happens when you deploy it? Now production db might have different triggers than your dev environment and good luck dealing with that.

Comment: Migrations shouldn't know something about models, and especially about some meta information (list of model classes). Migrations are just about migrations

Comment: I think what might be useful here is a generator instead that creates the migration to create the triggers if you're actually doing it enough times to warrant the effort. https://medium.com/@admanteza/creating-a-custom-migration-generator-in-rails-84fc5769882e

Comment: The "concern" is used to add annotations to the models. Similar to the `acts-as-taggable-on` gem but not exactly. So need to add a trigger that is generated depending on *all* models with that functionality. I'd rather have it automatically discover them, than leave people or myself list them manually. Blame me for it but I don't trust people. Whenever the migration is run, it will be valid for the current state of the models. The biggest issue I see is adding the annotations to a new model but forgetting to add a migration for the trigger. Listing models manually though won't be any better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To eager load a directory in a way that works well after reloads, do this:

```rb
# config/initializers/eager_load_foo.rb

# Run when the application boots, and on each reload.
Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
  Rails.autoloaders.main.eager_load_dir("#{Rails.root}/my/dir")
end
```

That needs Zeitwerk 2.6.2 or later ([docs](https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk#eager-load-directories)). Zeitwerk is also able to eager load namespaces if that would match better your use case ([docs](https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk#eager-load-namespaces)).

That won't conflict in production, because eager loading is idempotent (but compatible with reloading, as the example above shows).

Comment: Is it safe to do just `Rails.autoloaders.main.eager_load_dir("#{Rails.root}/my/dir")` just inside the rake task I need (not inside an initializer)?

Comment: I'm not marking this as accepted although it gives me the piece of information I was missing so far. Because my main question was how to cache these classes. The answer in a comment to this I've got (to my dissatisfaction) that basically you can't, one can cache them as strings and use `::const_get` afterwards. If you have other ideas or add this to your answer, it will be justified to mark it as accepted. Thanks for your answer either way!

Comment: You can, but then mentioning "reload" in the problem description is confusing. Rake tasks do not reload.

Comment: I don't know if somebody decides to reuse the method for something else some day... I'll just remove the memoization of classes and be done with it. Usage of these should not be encouraged and should not be needed for anything else anyway. The question about memoization is interesting though. It would affect any memoization of any classes.

Comment: Yeah, so if regular usage should be supported, then it has to go in the initializer (and the Rake task is expected to load the environment). Otherwise, in the task is enough. You are right, eager memoization and the deliberate laziness of dev mode go against each other. Docs for STI associations reflect this, it is a similar situation: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#single-table-inheritance

Comment: Let me add something. You can cache classes that are reloadable in a reload-friendly manner if they are cached in a reloadable place too. Otherwise, the comment about constant paths as strings to be `const_set` applies. Or you need a `to_prepare` callback that resets the collection. It would be cool to share the details of what your app exactly needs to be more precise.

Comment: This is an excellent point. In fact that is in a module that should be reloaded. I somehow didn't realize that it also would be reloaded and the memoization will be redone in such a case. I think this was the last piece as obvious as it may seem now. Thanks! Also I tried to add to the question an illustration of how I add these annotations. Let me know if it is still unclear.